# Would it be possible to write a parser generator for the Zend/PHP engine?

Tags: php, zend-framework, parser-generator

Out of curiosity, having been studying a few parser generator libraries (Flex, Bison, ANTLR, some LLVM related stuff), would it be possible to write a new parser generator for a pre-existing scripting language's engine such as PHP? I realize Facebook has basically done it except they wrote a whole new virtual machine to address issues they had with the Zend engine (?).

I've been able to create a few toy compiler examples for compiled VMs such as the JVM by generating the opcodes for a basic syntax and learning a lot of the JVM's class file structures and opcodes.

What intrigues me though is whether it's possible to replace Zend's PHP parser with your own without having to edit the core of the engine.

I ask this simply out of curiosity since I think it'd be an enjoyable little product to try work on some Zend/PHP engine languages that aren't source-to-source.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possibly, and a few alternatives to ZE have been developed over the years (Quercus Resin, IBM Project Zero, HippyVM, etc, PHPPHP and Recki-CT)

Comment: You've tagged `Zend Framework`, do you really mean that?

Comment: If software A does the same thing as software B, you can replace one with the other. It doesn't matter how it does it. So if you write a PHP parser using Flex/Bison, and it produces the same intermediate representation as the Zend parsser, then it should work. Of course, ensuring that it's completely compatible may be the difficult part.

Comment: @MarkBaker regarding the framework, probably not. I read some articles regarding "hacking the core of Zend" and it mentioned it and gave examples. 
Barmar I can't find out if the Zend engine has a way to do this though like built in. If I could pass a Zend-specified AST or something it'd make things a lot easier.

Comment: PHP7 apparantly parses to an AST.  Why don't you open it up and expose that machinery as a C library?